# cannot import name from partially initialized module

Tags: python

I have the following project and module setup:

[image]

class2.py:

```
from mod1.class1 import Class1


class Class2(object):
    def __init__(self, c1: Class1):
        self.c1 = c1
```

class2.py:

```
from mod2.class2 import Class2


class Class1(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.c2 = Class2(self)
```

main.py:

```
from mod1.class1 import Class1
from mod2.class2 import Class2

c1 = Class1()

c2 = Class2(c1)
```

The idea is that when a parent class initializing a child class, it introduces itself to the child class. This way the child class can call parent class methods.

This pattern works fine in strongly typed languages like C#.

When I run `main.py`, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Projects.Personal\exp02\main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from mod2.class2 import Class2
  File "C:\Projects.Personal\exp02\mod2\class2.py", line 2, in <module>
    from mod1.class1 import Class1
  File "C:\Projects.Personal\exp02\mod1\class1.py", line 1, in <module>
    from mod2.class2 import Class2
ImportError: cannot import name 'Class2' from partially initialized module 'mod2.class2' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Projects.Personal\exp02\mod2\class2.py)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I just need to let Class2 know about the type of Class1.

Why am I getting such error?

What is the proper pattern to do this in Python?

**Update #1**

I understand that this is a circular import as it is specifically stated in the error message.

The idea explained in this article (https://stackabuse.com/python-circular-imports/) is not applicable here. Here I have Classes not module functions. I just need to annotate a variable. My code sample is very much simplified. The actual classes code is large. I don't want to combine them in one file.

IMO, This is a valid pattern and I can do it in Java or C#.

How can I implement the idea in Python?

**Update #2:  TYPE_CHECKING did not work**

Per @RedKnite, I updated the class2.py to the following code:

```
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING
if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from mod2.class2 import Class2


class Class1(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.c2 = Class2(self)
```

I am getting the the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Projects.Personal\exp02\main.py", line 6, in <module>
    c1 = Class1()
  File "C:\Projects.Personal\exp02\mod1\class1.py", line 8, in __init__
    self.c2 = Class2(self)
NameError: name 'Class2' is not defined. Did you mean: 'Class1'?
```

Comment: You have a circular import issue.  I'd rethink how you setup your imports and classes.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `TYPE_CHECKING` flag from `typing` and make the class a string.
At runtime `TYPE_CHECKING` is False so the import will not execute, but a type checker should find this acceptable.

```
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING
if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from mod1.class1 import Class1

class Class2(object):
    def __init__(self, c1: "Class1"):
        self.c1 = c1
```

Comment: Thank you for help. It didn't work. Please see Update #2 in my question

Comment: The check needs to be in the file that defines Class2, because it needs to be in the file that contains the type hint. It looks like you put it in the file that defines Class1.

Answer (score 0):

You have a [circular import](https://stackabuse.com/python-circular-imports/). Your Class1 and Class2 files are attempting to import each other- i'd suggest using one file that imports both classes.

Comment: Please see the update #1 at the bottom of my question.